# What "password" am I being prompted for before a wipe?

Tags: lock-screens, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 with Verizon. I've also had my phone wiped 4 times because of our corporate policy requiring a device wipe after 4 or 5 attempts and, when hiking with my phone in my pocket, somehow triggering invalid fingerprint login attempts (my hands when hiking and climbing are definitely not in my pockets).

But my question here is what "password" I'm being prompted for right before my phone is wiped. It just says, "Please enter your password" (or something equally vague) and gives me an alphanumeric keyboard. In the past, I've tried my Google account password (tied to the phone) and even my PIN. This last time, I meticulously made sure I entered my Google account and the phone was wiped right before my summit bid (I was going to snap a photo and ended up loosing a few to date; the worst is when I lost some climbing route beta and we got off-route).

Here's my set up:

- I have a PIN set up (required by policy).
- I have fingerprints set up.
- I do not have a lock screen password (could this be it? Samsung said I should be prompted for one but support doesn't seem to understand what I'm asking about anyway).
- My Google account uses 2FA, so in most cases my raw Google password won't suffice. Do I need to generate an app password?

The phone is stock (i.e. not rooted and only apps from Google Play). The vague "password" screen looks the same as my lock screen PIN screen (i.e. alpha-blended with same font).

For now, I'm not planning on rejoining it to our corporate network but may want to in the future. I've also ordered a cover for when I'm hiking or climbing to hopefully avoid this situation (it's only ever happened in these situations). But should I be prompted again for this "password", I want to know what I'm supposed to enter before loosing everything and spending hours resetting up 2FAs for various sites, apps, etc. (the backups never seen to restore everything, but, then again, I'm usually trying to restore while on the fringe of network connectivity).

Comment: Without seeing the actual screen I'm just guessing here, but probably a corporate administrative password. Sounds like your corporate security policy for BYOD is pretty tight, try removing the corporate account and device administration rights before a factory reset.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do anything to get into my phone when this last prompt is shown. One chance, and it's all gone. Samsung support didn't know for certain either. I'm assuming, though, it's not some corporate password. There's nothing about this in the information provided, nor any instructions to call IT should we see this.

Comment: I don't know how far you want to go with this since it sounds like the device is working, but here is what I would do (this would drive me nuts)... Delete all accounts off the device in Settings-Accounts and remove all Device Administrators in Settings-Security, my guess is when you try to remove one of these you will get prompted, telling which one is the culprit... if not, do the factory reset, removing your Google account should remove any FRP.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "when you try to remove one of these you will get prompted". When I disable phone administrators, nothing much happens. I would assume that at some point (i.e. when a policy check is triggered) functionality that requires said administrative access may cease functioning, but this password dialog looks like it belongs to Android (or any shell customizations Samsung made). For what it looks like, take a look at a PIN prompt when unlocking the screen and imagine it was for a "password" instead with no other information.